# Cyclic "import xyz as abc"

Tags: python, import, module, cyclic-dependency

I have a problem when I try to have a cyclic import in Python 3. I am writing a PyQt4 app and I want to make some object available in the whole app. This way I end up having some files:

index.py

```
import source.blab as bl
```

source/blab.py

```
import source.windows
windows = source.windows.Windows()
```

source/windows.py

```
import source.window_clients.main_window

class Windows:
    ...
```

source/window_clients/main_window.py

```
import source.blab

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    ...
```

So far, the code works. However, for aesthetic reasons, I would like to change the import command in `main_window.py` into:

```
import source.blab as bl
```

which throws an:

```
AttributeError: module 'source' has no attribute 'blab'
```

I am sure, this is related to [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python) where they say that one cannot use `from a * import b` in a cyclic import. Is it the same for `import a as b`? If so, is there another way to change the name of the imported module?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024) that has been [fixed now](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f93234bb8a87855f295d441524e519481ce6ab13).
The reasons have to do with how the import statement was implemented in the different cases.